# RTC not saving workspace

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, workspace, rtc

So I connected to my workspace and loaded my source code in RTC. I then Imported my local workspace (the source code that I downloaded through RTC) into IntelliJ. I was having issues with IntelliJ loading duplicate modules.

I deleted my .idea folder and my .iml files. I also deleted me .jazz5 folder.

Since I deleted the .jazz5 folder is that why my workspace was not loaded the next time I opened RTC?

I am using Eclipse with the RTC plugin not RTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I deleted the .jazz5 folder is that why my workspace was not loaded the next time I opened RTC?

Yes: you need to "Load" again your repo workspace in that same path, in order for RTC to recreate the `.jazz5` folder: it designate the local workspace or sandbox.

Comment: And that folder is where my workspace is reloaded? Meaning when I boot RTC again that is where RTC will load my workspace from again. So I won't have to actually redownload my code.

Comment: @NoahHerron yes, once the .jazz5 is in place, you won't need to redownload.